# C# global anti-alias

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, antialiasing

I tried using `TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit` and it's great, but can it be applied to all labels and other text elements in the project at once? 
So that all toolbox elements in WindowForms would have the `AntiAliasGridFit`

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Font TextFont = new Font("Roboto", 25, FontStyle.Regular);
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    e.Graphics.DrawString("test", TextFont, Brushes.Black, 20, 20);
}
```